# Any reason why we should not set multipleSiteBindingsEnabled=true?

Tags: c#, wcf

In our WCF Web service, we recently solved a customer's problem by adding `<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled=”true”>` to the application's configuration file. This allowed the service to operate correctly, when IIS was configured with multiple bindings for the site containing the Web service, meaning that the Web service had multiple base addresses.

The question now is whether this setting is a good idea for all installations of our product. Does it have any downsides? If not, why is it not the default in WCF?

I have done some Web-searching and found multiple people explaining reasons why one *should* include this setting, but the only downside that I found was to do with "relayed endpoints", which are a concept with which I am unfamiliar and therefore something that I don't believe we are using.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what problem you solved enabling multipleSiteBindingsEnabled however if you are using multiple base url e.g. one for external users and one for internal users and you want to keep one of urls secrete then enabling multipleSiteBindingsEnabled will defy that purpose as all base address will be listed in WSDL/MEX information generated by the service. This could be one flip side of enabling multiple site bindings.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

I don't actually know why the multiple base addresses are used, and perhaps cannot even find out, as customers do not always want to explain all their security concerns to vendors. 

I believe that your point about WSDL/MEX information does not apply in our case, because we do not expose any metadata endpoints - we give people the WSDL and the endpoints are their own.